# QGis Embedded python cannot import pyo files

Tags: python, plugins, qgis

My problem is that I don't want to distribute .py files of a qgis plugin, I would like to distribute just pyo files.

What I have tried to do is:

> 1. Develop a simple plugin and ensure that it works correctly
> 2. Generate pyo files of the plugin calling python normally with "-OO -m py_compile" from command line, without qgis
> 3. Remove py files

After that QGis's python interpreter fails to load the plugin.

I was expected to get 'cannot find module..' error, but I get:
Cannot import module ...'

I think that this means that QGis sees my pyo files, but for some reason it cannot load them.

Any suggestions?